# Leaflet offset of tiled layer WMTS layer

Tags: coordinate-system, leaflet, wmts

Adding in Leaflet a WMTS layer with the 'L.tileLayer' to a COG Tiff results in an offset. Both services are in the same EPSG:2056 system

This code

```
<html>
<head>
    !-- Version 2.0 --> <!-- full stretch -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css"/>
    <style>
        #map {
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.6.0/proj4.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/georaster"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/georaster-layer-for-leaflet"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4leaflet/1.0.2/proj4leaflet.min.js"></script>


<script>
    // Define custom CRS for EPSG 2056
    var crs2056 = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:2056',
        "+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=2600000 +y_0=1200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs",
        {
            resolutions: [1024, 512, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625],
            origin: [2485071.58, 1299941.79],
        }
    );

    // Initialize Leaflet map with custom CRS
    var map = L.map('map', {
        crs: crs2056,
        maxZoom: crs2056.options.resolutions.length,

    }).setView([46, 8], 1);

    // Add TMS Layer
    L.tileLayer('https://wmts.asit-asso.ch/wmts/1.0.0/asitvd.fond_pourortho/default/default/0/2056/{z}/{y}/{x}.png', {
    maxZoom: crs2056.options.resolutions.length,
    tileSize: 128
    }).addTo(map);
 
    // Add WMTS Layer: Does not work since  Tilematrix is wrongly set with 20
    //var map4 = new L.TileLayer.WMTS("https://wmts.asit-asso.ch/wmts", {
    //  layer: 'asitvd.fond_pourortho',
    //  style: "default",
    //  format: 'image/png',
    //  tilematrixSet: "2056"
        
    //}).addTo(map);

    const url_to_geotiff_file = new URLSearchParams(location.search).get("url");
    console.log("url_to_geotiff_file:", url_to_geotiff_file);

    if (!url_to_geotiff_file) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            // If no URL is provided, redirect to a sample GeoTIFF
            const parser = new URL(window.location);
            parser.searchParams.set("url", "https://d29cp2gnktw6by.cloudfront.net/data/S2_LEVEL_2A/20240101T102431/S2_L2A_SR_20240101T102431_20240101T102428_10M_run20240102.tif");
            window.location = parser.href;
        }, 2 * 1000);
    } else {
        console.log("url_to_geotiff_file:", url_to_geotiff_file);
        // Parse the GeoTIFF data
        parseGeoraster(url_to_geotiff_file).then(function (georaster) {
            console.log("georaster:", georaster);
            // based on https://custom-scripts.sentinel-hub.com/custom-scripts/sentinel-2/l2a_optimized/    
        
        // Contrast enhance / highlight compress
        const maxR = 3.0; // max reflectance
        const midR = 0.13;
        const sat = 1.2;
        const gamma = 1.8;
        
        
        function evaluatePixel(val0,val1,val2) {
            //console.log("val0:", val0, "val1:", val1, "val2:", val2);
            const rgbLin = satEnh(sAdj(val0), sAdj(val1), sAdj(val2));
            //console.log("rgbLin:", rgbLin);
            //console.log("sRGB0:", sRGB(rgbLin[0]), "sRGB1:", sRGB(rgbLin[1]), "sRGB2:", sRGB(rgbLin[2]));
            return [sRGB(rgbLin[0]), sRGB(rgbLin[1]), sRGB(rgbLin[2])];
        }
        
        function sAdj(a) {
            return adjGamma(adj(a, midR, 1, maxR));
        }

        
        const gOff = 0.01;
        const gOffPow = Math.pow(gOff, gamma);
        const gOffRange = Math.pow(1 + gOff, gamma) - gOffPow;


        function adjGamma(b) {
            return (Math.pow((b + gOff), gamma) - gOffPow) / gOffRange;
        }
        
        // Saturation enhancement
        function satEnh(r, g, b) {
            const avgS = (r + g + b) / 3.0 * (1 - sat);
            return [clip(avgS + r * sat), clip(avgS + g * sat), clip(avgS + b * sat)];
        }

        function clip(s) {
            return s < 0 ? 0 : s > 1 ? 1 : s;
        }

        //contrast enhancement with highlight compression
        function adj(a, tx, ty, maxC) {
            var ar = clip(a / maxC, 0, 1);
            return ar * (ar * (tx / maxC + ty - 1) - ty) / (ar * (2 * tx / maxC - 1) - tx / maxC);
        }

        const sRGB = (c) => c <= 0.0031308 ? (12.92 * c) : (1.055 * Math.pow(c, 0.41666666666) - 0.055);


            const layer = new GeoRasterLayer({
                attribution: "Contains modified Copernicus Sentinel data 2024",
                debugLevel: 0,
                georaster,
                resolution: 128,
                opacity:1,
                resampleMethod: "nearest",
                pixelValuesToColorFn: values => {
                    // Check if any of the bands have a value of 9999 or 0
                    if (values.some(value => value === 9999 )) {
                    //if (values.some(value => value === 9999 || value === 0)) {
                        // If any band has a value of 9999 or 0, return transparent color
                        return 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'; // Transparent color
                    } else {
                        // Apply min-max normalization to each band
                        const r = Math.round(evaluatePixel(values[0]/10000, values[1]/10000, values[2]/10000)[0] * 255);
                        const g = Math.round(evaluatePixel(values[0]/10000, values[1]/10000, values[2]/10000)[1] * 255);
                        const b = Math.round(evaluatePixel(values[0]/10000, values[1]/10000, values[2]/10000)[2] * 255);


                        // Return RGB color
                        return `rgba(${r},${g},${b},1)`;
                    }
                }
            });

            layer.addTo(map);
            map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

results in this map

[image]

any ideas why the 'asitvd.fond_pourortho' tile layer is off in the up left corner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main problem is in the tile grid. WMTS layer from https://wmts.asit-asso.ch/ has the same projection, but different tile grid. There are some maps available from asit-asso.ch on https://asit-asso.ch/service/fonds-de-plan. Map is in OpenLayers. Source code inspection in browse debugger revealed the following about tile grid:

```
const ASITResolutions = [4000.0, 3750.0, 3500.0, 3250.0, 3000.0, 2750.0, 2500.0, 2250.0, 2000.0, 1750.0, 1500.0, 1250.0, 1000.0, 750.0, 650.0, 500.0, 250.0, 100.0, 50.0, 20.0, 10.0, 5.0, 2.5, 2.0, 1.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.1, 0.05];
const ASITMatrixIds = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29];
const WMTSOrigin = [2420000.0, 1350000.0];
```

These values have to be used on projection definition.

One other thing is that WMTS tile size is standard 256, so `tileSize: 128` option should be left out.

Relevant part of the code then looks something like this:

```
var crs2056 = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:2056',
   "+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=2600000 +y_0=1200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs",
   {
     resolutions: [4000.0, 3750.0, 3500.0, 3250.0, 3000.0, 2750.0, 2500.0, 2250.0, 2000.0, 1750.0, 1500.0, 1250.0, 1000.0, 750.0, 650.0, 500.0, 250.0, 100.0, 50.0, 20.0, 10.0, 5.0, 2.5, 2.0, 1.5, 1.0, 0.5, 0.25, 0.1, 0.05],
     origin: [2420000.0, 1350000.0]
 });

var map = L.map('map', {
  crs: crs2056
}).setView([46, 8], 1);

L.tileLayer('https://wmts.asit-asso.ch/wmts/1.0.0/asitvd.fond_pourortho/default/default/0/2056/{z}/{y}/{x}.png', {
  maxZoom: crs2056.options.resolutions.length,
  zIndex: 5
}).addTo(map);
```

This is then the result:

[image]

Comment: I was looking at this service in QGIS, I can can get the KVP service to work, but all the ZYX requests are invalid, though hand crafted comparable requests return results.   I guess that QGIS is assuming one grid set for the zoom level and sending inappropriate requests.